# Date slicer not correctly filtering dates

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I have multiple tables with hundreds of rows in each sharing the same date/time.  I put a slicer on my report to filter and SUM the rows with the matching dates.  However, the visual only returns the value of the first row with the matching date, not the sum of all the rows with that date..... Not sure what I might be doing wrong?  I made a "many:many" both direction relationship between my calendar table and the data table.

Comment: why do you have a many to many relationship between calendar and data????

Comment: At the moment it's because my calendar has more dates than exist in the data so being the date table has more unique values I thought it would be the way to go??

Comment: That's not what many to many relationships are for. Your Calendar table will always have more dates than your transaction table. The important bit is that each date in the transaction table can be linked to ONE date in the calendar table. You need a one to many relationship from the calendar (one date) to the transaction (many transactions with the same date).

Comment: I tried that and it said "not a valid relationship" for all of them except many to many....

Comment: Cardinality not valid for this type of relationship.  I just tried again.

Comment: Does your calendar table have duplicate dates? It shouldn't. Each date should appear only once in the calendar table. That date should be the key by which you create the relationship to dates in other tables. Then you cannot and don't need to setup a many to many relationship. Maybe you need to read up a bit about what a calendar table is, what it does and how to set it up. Plenty of tutorials available with a simple search.